# Lanzar programa usando cmd desde Java

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

Quiero lanzar un programa desde la ejecución de mi programa en java. El comando que uso en el cmd seria este cambiando user, password y url:

"start /B /D "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Juniper Networks\Integration" pulselauncher -u ' user ' -p ' password ' -url https://url.com -r pepe"

Me sale error y ya no sé como intentarlo, podríais echarme un cable? Gracias
Y el código que uso es:

```
public static void abrirConexionPulseSecure() {
    try {

        String [] cmd = {
                "start", 
                "/B",
                "/D",
                "\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Juniper Networks\\Integration\"",
                "pulselauncher", 
                "-u", 
                USER, 
                "-p", 
                PASSWORD, 
                "-url", 
                "https://url.com", 
                "-r", 
                "pepe" };

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        System.out.println("Conexion establecida.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Y el error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at utils.ConexionBBDD.abrirConexionPulseSecure(ConexionBBDD.java:78)
    at test.TestGestionFicheros.main(TestGestionFicheros.java:30)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Dices que te da un error. ¿Cúal es? Estás omitiendo la parte más importante de la pregunta

Comment: Ya está editado, se me olvidó ponerlo, sorry.

Comment: Donde existe el programa start y/o el alías a start, en que carpeta ejecutas ese programa o batch?

Comment: Has probado a quitar los 3 primeros strings? lanzar el comando sin usar "start"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No uso windows así que no puedo asegurar al 100% que esta solución funcione, pero algo como lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
String [] cmd = {
            "cmd.exe", //añadiendo primero el ejecutable que lanza la consola         
            "/c",
            "start", 
            "/B",
            "/D",
            "\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Juniper Networks\\Integration\"",
            "pulselauncher", 
            "-u", 
            USER, 
            "-p", 
            PASSWORD, 
            "-url", 
            "https://url.com", 
            "-r", 
            "pepe" };

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Explicación: El problema es que "start" es una orden interna del intérprete de comandos, como "dir" o "cd". Es decir, no existe un ejecutable "start.exe" o un "cd.exe" al que llamar, tienes que *pedir* a cmd.exe que realicen esa acción.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora si que si.

Comment: Lo único por si le puede valer a alguien en un futuro es añadir entre "cmd.exe" y "start" el comando **"c/"**

Comment: Añadido a la respuesta, gracias por el aporte :)